# SQL varchar to datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I see this question being asked many times but I have some extra factors that I don't see answers take account for.

Here's the scenario. I have some dates (in varchar at the moment) that I have stored in my table. It has come time to convert these dates into datetimes and have all future dates stored properly. From newsapi.org, I get articles (titles, descriptions, and **dates** in this format 2017-05-03T00:48:09Z)

Two questions:
What sql code can I execute to convert this column of strings into a datetime?

Edit:
I tried this but I got an error. I even edited my php.ini file

```
MariaDB [default]> UPDATE News SET ts=CAST(publishedAt AS TIMESTAMP);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMP)' at line 1
```

What sort of php will allow me to take such a string and properly put it into an "insert into" statement?

Edit
When trying to run Ahmed Ginani answer I get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.' in /var/www/html/news/news.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/news/news.php(32): DateTime->__construct('2017-05-10T18:0...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/news/news.php on line 32
```

using

```
foreach ($obj->articles as &$article)
{
        $title = htmlspecialchars($article->title, ENT_QUOTES);
        $author = htmlspecialchars($article->author, ENT_QUOTES);
        $description = htmlspecialchars($article->description, ENT_QUOTES);
        $url = htmlspecialchars($article->url, ENT_QUOTES);
        $urlToImage = htmlspecialchars($article->urlToImage, ENT_QUOTES);
        $date = (new DateTime($article->publishedAt))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


        $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO News (author, title, description, url, urlToImage, ts) VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $author . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $url . "', '" . $urlToImage . "', $date)";

        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
        {
                echo "New Record Successfuly Created <br>";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
                echo "<br><br>";
        }
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
select CAST('2017-05-03T00:48:09Z' AS TIMESTAMP);
```

Works on all ISO / ANSI compliant databases I know ...

Apparently, MariaDB can't CAST() to a TIMESTAMP type ...
Then, using the docu found here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/str_to_date/ , try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(publishedAt,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ');
```

Here, I'm assuming that a format of: `2017-05-03T23:48:09Z` is valid: 24-hour time depiction.

Comment: How do I apply this to my table's column in mysql workbench? I think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Either `INSERT INTO foo (ts_as_varchar,ts)  SELECT ts_as_varchar, CAST(ts_as_varchar AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM source_tb;` or: `ALTER TABLE foo ADD ts TIMESTAMP(0);` followed by `UPDATE foo SET ts=CAST(ts_as_varchar AS TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Going by the 2nd example, you're making a new column on the table right? After that is ts_as_varchar my column with all my varchars going into the new ts? Or do I have to select all and iterate through them?

Comment: Exactly. I assume your initial table to be (ignoring any possible other columns): `CREATE TABLE foo (ts_as_varchar VARCHAR(32));` The table is loaded, and contains, in `ts_as_varchar`, all literals in the format you mentioned. So you add a column of type TIMESTAMP (which will contain NULLs initially), and then fill those columns using the UPDATE statement I show above, with no WHERE condition, so that all rows of the table are affected in one statement. It's possible that the execution of that statement could take a while.

Comment: I'm using mariadb. I get an error when trying to run that statement.. See edit.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. Do you have any idea what is wrong with my php error? I can't seem to reach the other person who answered.

Comment: I don' t program in php, I'm afraid. I would browse the internet on php documentation for DateTime() and DateTimeZone. The example set it to 'UTC'; maybe it needs to be lowercase? Does the format string need percent signs like the STR_TO_DATE() function in SQL? These are just ideas ...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code
Note the 'Z' at the end which means Zulu (a.k.a UTC) so it might be worth converting your date and time to UTC as follows:

```
<?php
$date = (new DateTime('2017-05-03T00:48:09Z'))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```